# I need to adjust logo using custom size in the wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, web, plugins, elementor, graphical-logo

I need to enlarge the logo of my website named [Check MOT History](https://checkmothistory.uk/), I tried the image logo resize plug-in but it's not working properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what you need to give us so that we might be able to help. Then update your question with details of what you have tried and your *relevant code* in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Elementor the only way (apart from custom CSS) is to change the size in the elementor theme builder. I would recommend [this guide](https://docs.elementor.com/article/335-create-headers-using-elementors-theme-builder) if you don't already have a header template or are not familiar with it. Once you areediting your header you can simply change the size by selecting your logo and using the slider.

Another way would be to check the astra theme settings. Go into your wordpress dashboard --> Design --> Customizer. There you should find the logo option where you initially uploaded your image.